# Antlr failed to create lookahead

Tags: antlr, xtext

I have a grammar that is not really super clean considering the notation therefore I have to turn on backtracking for it
 (I know that this is not the best solution but as my grammar is being generated by a program I write and fixing these parts will take me a lot time for debugging but that's not the topic here).

However when I try to generate my grammar via the Mwe2 workflow it gives me this error message:

```
error(10):  internal error: org.antlr.tool.Grammar.createLookaheadDFA(Grammar.java:1279): could not even do k=1 for decision 92; reason: timed out (>100000ms)
```

As I have read [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/165624/) this may be because Antlr just needs more time for compiling...
My question is if it would be sufficient to just increase the time Antlr can take to generate (and if yes how to do this) or if this may have other reasons such as an endless loop during creation or something similar...

Note: My grammar is almost 3000 lines long

Thanks in advance
Raven

**EDIT**:
When increasing the conversion time to 5 million ms the above error disappears but nevertheless I end up with a bunch of exceptions:

```
[ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: Generator)
     org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment.generate(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.DefaultGeneratorFragment.generate(DefaultGeneratorFragment.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:173)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:613)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:756)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:756)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)

[ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: Generator)
     org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment.generate(XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.DefaultGeneratorFragment.generate(DefaultGeneratorFragment.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:173)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.HashMap.newNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:630)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:756)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Problems running workflow raven.GenerateSQF: 
[ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: Generator)
     org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment.generate(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.DefaultGeneratorFragment.generate(DefaultGeneratorFragment.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:173)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:613)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:756)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:756)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)

[ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: Generator)
     org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment.generate(XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.DefaultGeneratorFragment.generate(DefaultGeneratorFragment.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:173)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.HashMap.newNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.putVal(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:630)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:756)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)

    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
[ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: Generator)
     org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment.generate(XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.DefaultGeneratorFragment.generate(DefaultGeneratorFragment.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:173)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:613)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:756)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:756)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:683)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:709)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)
    at org.antlr.analysis.NFAToDFAConverter.closure(NFAToDFAConverter.java:765)

[ERROR]: GeneratorException: (Element: -UNKNOWN-; Reported by: Generator)
     org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.AntlrToolFacade.runWithEncodingAndParams(AntlrToolFacade.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.parser.antlr.XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment.generate(XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.DefaultGeneratorFragment.generate(DefaultGeneratorFragment.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.CompositeGeneratorFragment.generate(CompositeGeneratorFragment.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.generate(Generator.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.generator.Generator.invokeInternal(Generator.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.Mwe2Bridge.invoke(Mwe2Bridge.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe.core.lib.AbstractWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractWorkflowComponent.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.invoke(AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.Workflow.run(Workflow.java:19)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.run(Mwe2Launcher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher.main(Mwe2Launcher.java:36)
```

Comment: did you try to increase the timeout http://sowjitechblog.blogspot.de/2014/06/increase-conversion-time-for-xtext.html (the nuber has to be bigger than 100000 in your case)

Comment: Yes tried it with 200000ms but still get the same error...

Comment: what about making the numer really really big?

Comment: I tried it with 1.2 million ms but it gave me the same error (actually it pretends that it has been more than 100000ms so I guess Antlr has some sort of limitation?)

Comment: forget the above...Just forgot to also change the UIGeneratorFragment indtead of just the GenaeratorFragment. I updated my question...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022966/xtext-what-does-this-exception-mean

Comment: Well that's actually my own question xD But thank you!

Comment: Okay I increased the heap space to 6gb and am still getting the same problem... I think it can't really be that Xtext needs that much space so I rather think there is some internal problem with my grammar caused by my grammar itself ut isn't reported or just an internal Xtext bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to increase the conversion timeout you need to use this option :

```
fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrUiGeneratorFragment auto-inject {
      antlrParam = "-Xconversiontimeout" antlrParam = "30000"
}

fragment = parser.antlr.XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment auto-inject {
       antlrParam = "-Xconversiontimeout" antlrParam = "30000"
}
```

Comment: Well you actually were right... If you edit our answer so that one also has to change the XtextAntlrGeneratorFragment (not just the UI one) I will mark your answer as the correct one